# Allocating a std::string with std::vector iterators causes debug errors in one project, but works in another?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, iterator

I am trying to get the name of an input device, using the RawInput API, but I get a weird error when I allocate the name string.Basically I saw this in another project where it worked perfectly.This is the flawed code:

```
std::string Input::GetDeviceName(void* device)
{
    size_t size;

    bool result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(device, RIDI_DEVICENAME, null, &size) ;
    if(result < 0)
    {
        throw RawInputException(GetLastError(), L"GetRawInputDeviceInfo(InputDeviceDataRequest::Name)");
    }

    std::vector<std::string::value_type> data(size);

    result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(device, RIDI_DEVICENAME, &data[0], &size);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        throw RawInputException(GetLastError(), L"GetRawInputDeviceInfo(InputDeviceDataRequest::Name)");
    }
    std::string name = std::string(data.cbegin(), data.cend());
    return(name);
}
```

The same code worked fine in the tutorial implementation i read it from, however when I use it it triggers a breakpoint at ***HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1);***, somewhere 10 levels down the call stack from **std::string _name = std::string(data.cbegin(), data.cend());**.I checked the value of the vector, it has a size of 61.I think the problem is with the actual contents?But what could go wrong with std::string::value_type?GetRawInputDeviceInfo() returns true, so it successfully filled up the vector with chars.And as I mentioned, the tutorial code where I read it from built and ran perfectly.For those interested, here's a link to the project: [The guy stopped updating it, but its almost fully functional](https://code.google.com/p/rawinput/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the fact that depending on your compiler options, the string is expected to either be composed of `char` or `wchar_t`. So, instead of using `std::string`, you should be using `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`. Also, you might want to look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956504/would-stdbasic-stringtchar-be-preferable-to-stdwstring-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with this particular API, but give this a try:

```
std::vector<std::string::value_type> data(size+1);
```

If that prevents the breakpoint, then it's because GetRawInputDeviceInfo terminates the string with a \0 but doesn't include it in the count.  If so, it's writing past the end of the space you allocated, potentially corrupting the heap.  Most MS APIs don't work like that but I do find their APIs aren't always perfectly behaved.

Since (if my theory is right) the buffer you're providing is only one character too short, it's quite possible that it will work fine under some conditions (stl implementation, compiler, memory conditions, etc.) and not under others.  Memory corruption doesn't have consistent results.

If this does avoid the breakpoint, don't forget that your resulting `std::string` will have a \0 at the end, as part of the string.  If you don't want that, also fix this:

```
std::string name = std::string(data.cbegin(), data.cend()-1);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also just shorten it to: `return std::string(data.cbegin(), data.cend()-1);`